# NodeJs, socket.io, IE

Tags: javascript, node.js, internet-explorer, socket.io

I have nodeJS app, where i have to use `socket.io`. On client in page i have this code:

```
var serverBaseUrl = document.href;
var socket = io.connect(serverBaseUrl, {'sync disconnect on unload' : true})
socket.on('connect', function () {
    alert("socket connect");
    sessionId = (socket.io.engine.id).toString().substr(0, 10);
    console.log("socket.io connected : " + sessionId);
});
```

NodeJS code:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('../service/sockets').startServer(server);
```

startServer function:

```
io.listen(server).on('connection', handler);
```

But this code does not fire in IE ( i test 9 and 11 versions ).

In Chrome and other it works perfectly. Also, there are interesting thing: i start server using `npm start`, then open a tab in IE and there are no socket connection, then i shut down process of nodes application and start it again and NOW, after start, IE fires event connect and i have socket session.

Any ideas what happens?

Comment: The socket connection is initiated by the client; you'll need to share your client JS to get help with your problem.

Comment: My question first code section - it is JS on client

Comment: Oh I see. Can you share the entire thing though? You should have a line somewhere for the socket to connect. Example: `var socket = io('http://localhost');`. Include the relevant node.js code as well.

Comment: Added to entire question

Comment: I'm not sure what `document.href` is; it returns undefined in Chrome and FF.

Try to do a little debugging. Have you checked the JS console for any errors? Are you sure what "serverBaseUrl" is for each browser? Could you include the node.js code that starts the socket?

Comment: Brilliant! You are right about `document.href`!! Wright it as answer - i'll mark it!

Comment: Actually document.href does not work in IE properly and i change it to document.URL which works, but it does not help me to resolve my issue. IE still can't obtain socket correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in a lot of alerts after socket.connect operation. So, the order was next:
1. alert
2. socket connect
3. alert
4. alert

When a delte 3 and 4 alerts - my codes starts to work. Don't know why yet, i some one knows - please write me.

**UPDATE**:

The problem was in console.log. Object console does not exist in IE without Developer Tools opening. So, delete all console.log and all works!

Comment: `alerts()` in the wrong place can disrupt timing and cause timeouts.  You should pretty much never use `alert()` for debugging.  Use `console.log()` as it won't causing timing issues.

Comment: i can't use console.log while coding for IE, because when i open Developing  Tools in IE to see console - everything works!!!